# how to change 'numbers' in user input to be the starting point of a loop

Tags: python, loops, input

I'm making a program to test a game called Baccarat, and I have a few of the basics down, but I need help so that the user can copy and past many games at once and example would be like this

```
games = input('what are the games you want to test ')

players input(1,B,T,P,B,B,B,P,P,P,T,P,P,P,P,T,B,P,P,B,P,P,B,B,P,P,B,P,B,P,T,B,T,B,P,P,T,B,P,P,B,P,P,T,P,P,P,P,P,B,P,B,B,P,B,B,P,B,B,P,B,B,B,B,P,B,P,B,P,T,P,B,B,B,P,B,B,P,P,P
2,T,P,B,P,B,B,P,P,B,B,T,P,B,B,T,P,P,B,B,B,B,P,T,B,T,B,B,B,P,P,B,P,P,P,B,P,B,P,T,B,P,B,P,B,B,B,B,P,B,B,B,P,P,P,B,T,B,P,B,B,P,B,B,P,B,P,P,B,B,P,P,P,B,B,P,B,P,P,P,P,T
3,P,P,B,B,P,B,T,T,B,P,P,B,B,B,P,B,B,P,P,B,P,T,P,B,P,P,P,P,B,B,B,P,B,T,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,B,P,B,B,P,B,B,P,T,B,P,P,P,B,B,B,P,P,B,P,P,B,B,P,P,P,B,P,B,P,B,B,B,B,B,B,P,P,T,B,P,B,P,P)
```

I know very little basics of python programming and made a program to manully type in when you win and get the same results but I want to be able to paste and copy a 100 games at once but whats stumping me is that I don't know how to make the loop start at each number

example of code (the best I can logically put it)

```
bank = 1000
for number in games:
     number = games[0]
     if games[2] == 'B':
        bank += 7.60
     elif games[4] == 'B':
        bank += 6.25
```

so I want the program to start at `games[0]` which would be '1' then `games[2]` is the first 'B' and I want the program to stop there and start at the number '2' and start the loop again

thank you to anyone that could answer my question

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop. For loops can run a piece of code for every element in an object.  That is, you don't need the `number = games[0]` line. After changing the `bank +=` and `bank -=`, this should work:

```
bank = 100
for n in games:
    if n == 'B':
        bank += 7  #Anything can be here, even a function to determine the value
    elif n == 'P':
        bank -= 7  #Again, can be anything.
    elif n == 'T':
        bank += 1
```

Comment: what if I want to bet a sequence such as 8,15,35,60,20,20 and everytime a 'P' hits it will loop through the betting sequence like this                                                                 'P'=-8                                                              'P'=-15                                                             'B' = + 35

Comment: what I need the program to do is take the user input such as the first example above and play each game either till if bank > bank + 4 or till hand 40 and I want it to play the sequence 8,15,35,60,20,20 over and over til the origianl bank is atlease +4 or keep playing adding to the bank til either + 4 or til the 40th 'b' 'p' or 't' and then finish the sequence incase it doesnt hit a 'B' at hand 40 then start again at the next 'number'